# Mitsubishi L200 Warrior rear electric window issue

Tags: electrical, mitsubishi

My rear window has stopped working and the interior light in between the front and back seats as well.

I can find the interior light fuse, although the interior light by the rear view mirror works.

Also, my parking sensors have stopped working ( these were not factory fitted so am unsure were they are wired in).

But I cannot find the rear window fuse. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a fuse for only one door, but for both rear doors or even all 4. The fuse box is under the steering wheel on the left side. The other one (but don't need in your case) is under the hood near battery. Pull every fuse one after another and check them, or look at the car manual where it is. If this is not the fuse, there muss be a short circuit  of window engine or cable break somewhere.